# How to use Keras and TensorFlow to find the mode of a number?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to tensorflow and Convolutional Neural Networks, and I would like to build an AI that learns to find the mode of floating point numbers. But whenever I try to run the code, I run into some errors.
Here is my code so far:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

train_data = [
    [0.5, 0.2, 0.2],
    [0.3, 0.3, 0.4],
    [0.4, 0.4, 0.5],
    [0.8, 0.8, 0.1]
    ]

train_labels = [
    2.0,
    3.0,
    4.0,
    8.0
    ]

test_data = [
    [0.2, 0.5, 0.2],
    [0.7, 0.1, 0.7],
    [0.6, 0.8, 0.8]
    ]

test_labels = [
    2,
    7,
    8
    ]

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

EPOCHS = 2
BATCH_SIZE=1

model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

However, when I try and run the code I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 511, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1175, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 977, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("metrics/acc/Cast_6:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testNeural.py", line 38, in <module>
    metrics=['accuracy'])
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpointable\base.py", line 442, in _method_wrapper
    method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 499, in compile
    sample_weights=self.sample_weights)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1844, in _handle_metrics
    return_stateful_result=return_stateful_result))
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1801, in _handle_per_output_metrics
    metric_result = _call_stateless_fn(metric_fn)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1777, in _call_stateless_fn
    return weighted_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred, weights=weights, mask=mask)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 647, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 1533, in binary_accuracy
    return K.mean(math_ops.equal(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 3093, in equal
    "Equal", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 547, in _apply_op_helper
    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: so what are the updates? did you try implementing any answer, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions

1. use known data types such as numpy float32 instead of python 2d lists
2. the input shape clearly is not (1,)
3. try using regression +LSTMs for this task
4. you have 1 output neuron so why softmax?!
5. sparse_categorical_accuracy instead of accuracy

Comment: Point 4 here is wrong, softmax works fine with cross entropy losses, its the right combination.

Comment: I mean, you have 1 output neuron so why softmax?!

Comment: Yes that is a problem, but its not related to the choice of loss. People could be misled if you say softmax is somehow incompatible with a cross entropy loss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to do classification, and as such should use integer values for the class.

But the approach is wrong since you are using a single neuron to predict multiple classes but also because classification can't solve this issue. You should instead try to do regression. Classification should be used when having a limited number of possible classes, whereas regression can be used to predict values never seen before based on the patterns learned.

For regression to arbitrary values use None as the activation and mse for the loss.

For regression to values between 0 and 1  use sigmoid activation and mse or binary_crossentropy for the loss.